# Installing Deepin Terminal

Tags: pantheon-terminal

I just checked out the new Deepin 15.3 Release. 
But I'm more comfortable with elementary OS. I find the New Deepin Terminal Awesome. Any way to install this New Deepin Terminal on elementary OS Loki?
Thanks

Comment: Deepin is based on Debian. Assuming they have packaged all of their software in the convential Debian format, you should be able to add their repository to `/etc/sources/list.d/deepin.list` and install the terminal. You will need to first locate their repository however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways.

- The first way is  build source code
  https://github.com/linuxdeepin/deepin-terminal
- The second way is add deepin  to sources list then 
  `sudo apt install deepin-terminal`
  http://nekomiao.me/2016/08/10/ubuntu-1604-install-deepin-terminal/